# How to get descendant span element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:search_rate(this, 'key', 'upvote', 'url' );">
    <div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> <span class="rating">0</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

In the function search_rate, I would like to use the this variable that I passed to get the  element with class="rating" and then update its value from 0 to 1. I am using jQuery and I wrote the following to try to get the element:

```
update_node = $(this).find('.rating');
```

However, for some reason update_node does not point to the correct DOM element. Just to clarify I am a beginner and have been struggling with how to use jQuery to navigate the DOM. Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The jQuery is fine, the HTML is wrong. I don't think `DIV` is allowed as a child of `A`.

Comment: `this` will be the window inside your function, show function declaration. Need to use first named argument instead of `this`

Comment: The this is actually caller in the function. I just changed the name here because I thought it would be redundant to paste the whole thing...

Comment: not redundant when you show `this` without context though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery you don't need to pass a function through `href`. You don't need to use an `a` tag at all. Just target the `div` clicked and update its child `.rating`

**HTML**

```
<div class="upvote">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> 
    <span class="rating">0</span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".upvote").click(function(){
   $(this).find(".rating").html("1");    
});
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zgmpg92/1/)

**NOTE:** if you're looking to do an upvote count system, I would pull the number on page load and add 1 to it on click:

```
//pull current number
var currentCount = $(".upvote .rating").text();

$(".upvote").click(function(){ 
  $(this).find(".rating").html(parseInt(currentCount)+1); 
});
```

[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8zgmpg92/3/)

## **UPDATE**

To pass other values to the click event, just add them as data attributes:

```
<div class="upvote" data-one="hello" data-two="goodbye">
```

[**EXAMPLE 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zgmpg92/4/)

Comment: just pull the current text in the click handler in order to increment. On a list of 100 elements each with a rating would be far simpler

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I understand what you mean. The reason why I did that href is because I need to pass different arguments to that function search_rate depending on the item in a list that was clicked so I am not sure how I would do this with the click action on the div you suggested.

Comment: @Andrew just pass what ever you want as data attributes and you can pull them on the click event. I updated my answer

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure I follow you. Are you saying just use `$(this).text()` instead of finding `.rating`?

Comment: no I'm saying do something like `$(this).find(".rating").text(function(_,rateText){  return parseInt(rateText,10)+1; });`

Comment: @charlietfl yeah that's good too, except that will keep counting if you keep clicking. Not sure if OP wants that or a one-vote-per-person type of system

Comment: @Andrew no problem. Glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved?